# How do I download a new Ubuntu release without installing it?

Tags: ubuntu, cache, apt, upgrade

I want to upgrade - in this case, from Ubuntu Trusty to Vivid (going through Utopic if necessary) but I'd really rather do the upgrade in two parts, doing a dry run to get all the packages locally cached when I have an idle network (i.e.: overnight, not during the day) and then doing the installation part when I have time to sit and watch the machine (i.e.: when I am awake and interacting with it).

I'm aware that I might be able to trick `apt-get` into doing this by monkeying with `sources.list` and then doing an `apt-get dist-upgrade --download-only`, but:

1. will those packages actually persist when I run `do-release-upgrade`, or does that purge all the caches first?
2. will this have any unsupported / bad interactions with the supported upgrade path?

I do want to follow the supported upgrade path as much as possible, I'd just like to be able to download packages ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

According to [askubunutu: how to upgrade from an iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image) you can upgrade using the .iso, which would make it possible for you to just download the iso and and use it upgrade (mount it, burn a cd from it or dd it to a usb drive)